# Laravel RESTful Controller Redirects on POST only

Tags: php, rest, laravel

I have a RESTful controller that was created. When I attempt to create a new resource (POST) it redirects me to a 404.

/app-container/public/index.php/api/v1 ->

/index.php/api/v1 ->

/api/v1 -> 404

Here is my route for the controller:

```
Route::resource('restauranthours', 'restaurantHoursController');
```

Here is my controller:

```
class restaurantHoursController extends \BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
}


/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
    return "Create";
}


/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    //
    return "Store";
}


/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
    $day = $_GET['day'];
    return Response::json(DB::select('select * from restaurantHours where restId=? and day=? order by day',array($id, $day)));
}


/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}


/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    //
    return "Update";
}


/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
} }
```

If I use GET or PUT it gives me the values shown. It only redirects on POST.

Answer (score 1):

PUT doesn't create a new resource; it updates an existing resource. POST creates a new resource.

Comment: Yes, I meant to write "POST". It is redirecting when POSTing to the url. I have edited the question.